# Function returned by decorator isn't being executed when calling the decorated function. Am I missing something obvious?

Tags: python, logic, python-decorators

I had a go at writing a little function for making it easier to create decorators with arguments:

```py
def decoratorAddSupportForOptionalArguments(addToDict: typing.Callable):
    """Takes a function with arguments, where the first argument is callable and returns a modified version that enables decorator like syntax.
    """
    def addToDictDecorator(*argumentsPassedTo_addToDict, **kargumentsPassedTo_addToDict):
        kargumentsPassedTo_addToDict_keys = kargumentsPassedTo_addToDict.keys()
        if len(argumentsPassedTo_addToDict) == 1 and callable(argumentsPassedTo_addToDict[0]) and 0==len(kargumentsPassedTo_addToDict_keys):
            returnVal= addToDict(argumentsPassedTo_addToDict[0])
            return returnVal if returnVal!=None else addToDict
        # addToDict is being called as a function
        def decFinal(func):
            returnVal = addToDict(func,*argumentsPassedTo_addToDict, **kargumentsPassedTo_addToDict)
            print(f"decFinal {func.__name__} {returnVal}")
            return returnVal if returnVal!=None else addToDict
        return decFinal
    return addToDictDecorator
```

Which is supposed to be used as following:

```py
myDict=dict()
import random
@decoratorAddSupportForOptionalArguments
def addToDict(func, key=None, log=None):
    print("addToDict")
    myDict[key if key else str(random.random())]=func
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): # @note This is supposed to be called every time the decorated function gets called.
        print("foo")              # It never gets called however - and I cant figure out whats wrong
        if log:
            print(log)
        func(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper

@addToDict
def isValid(value):
    return value != None
@addToDict("myFancyKey")
def isPrivate(value):
    return value.__name__.startswith("_")
@addToDict()
def printRandom(value):
    print(random.random())
@addToDict("notepad",log="Starting notepad")
def startNotepad():
    import os
    print("notepad")
    os.system("notepad.exe")
print(myDict)
myDict["notepad"]()
myDict["notepad"]()
myDict["notepad"]()
```

Every time I attempt executing any of the functions prefixed with `addToDict`, "decFinal" gets executed like intended, but its return value (which in my example is `wrapper` inside of `addToDict` never gets called. To my understanding, the `@` decorator syntax should execute any function returned by what is returned by the decorator. What am I missing here? Every time `startNotepad` gets executed, I expect to see "foo" from `wrapper` get printed.

Interestingly, "foo" does get printed when I try invoking "isValid", which was declared with `@addToDict` without the parenthesis (unlike `startNotepad` ). It's just that, the logic does basically the same thing in both cases, except startNotepad first needs to call `decFinal` before foo finally gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you add func to the dictionary, instead of the wrapped version. So only `startNotepad()` actually prints foo - because it's decorated version, not `myDict['notepad']()` - because it's original function

So instead of this:

```py
def addToDict(func, key=None, log=None):
    print("addToDict")
    myDict[key if key else str(random.random())]=func # here, func is original undecorated version! 
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("foo")              
        if log:
            print(log)
        func(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

You gotta add wrapper. So that line had to be below the local function:

```py
def addToDict(func, key=None, log=None):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("foo")              
        if log:
            print(log)
        func(*args,**kwargs)
    print("addToDict")
    myDict[key if key else str(random.random())]=wrapper # fixed!  
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was looking in the wrong place the whole time!! (So typical me)